# What are difference between deploying an PWA on heroku and Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, github, heroku, strapi

I have following this tutorial https://strapi.io/blog/build-a-blog-with-react-strapi-and-apollo because I want to create a blog with posts with React in an easy way. But it seems they are deploying the app in the Heroku cloud platform, and I was wondering if it´s possible to not use Heroku and use Github Pages since it´s free or maybe use another free alternative. Also if it cannot be used why and what is the difference between both. I thought it didn't matter if an app is deploying to Github Pages or to the Heroku cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You need work with index.html on GitHub Pages . Heroku can work with npm and start your react app.
For example you can't just open html file and to see your project on reactJS , because React JS render your web site.
And you need to add this buildpack https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git if you want to deploy a new react project without server

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is a container hosting service and github pages are a static site hosting. In github pages you need to build and push the build files in the git repo(this was the case sometime back atleast, not sure if we can add build scripts now). In heroku we can add our own build scripts, send in env variables, monitor and scale. 
While you can use github pages for static sites and websites, but in case of pwa i don't recommend pwa. Heroku offers react templates to bootstrap deployment. However there are other factors like team size, pricing, how frequent are your deployments. Another advantage of heroku is you can use docker containers too. So if you want to run the pwa via ngnix server you can run it in the docker image, pass your own configurations like proxy and such in ngnix.conf and deploy the container in heroku cloud. I hope it answers your question.